# Disable div click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `<div>` with width and height properties. I want to put `<div>` over it, so the click events of the first `<div>` will not be registered anymore.

For example, I have div and when I click on it something is happening, but when I put second `<div>` over the first, clicking on the first `<div>` area will now fire that click events anymore.

```
<div id="firstDiv" style="width:100px; height:100px">bla bla</div>
```

How to put another `<div>` over "firstDiv" so I will not be able to change its elements? Is it possible?

Comment: It's invalid (not standard) to have multiple html elements with the same id. I suggest you use `class` instead.

Comment: This is a great example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just to disable click event to a div don't place extra div over it just use `on()` and `off()` from jQuery

**Details :** [ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ,[OFF](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

**Still if you want to place a div over another try using [css positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)**

Answer (score 2):

A nice way I've seen it done, and done it myself is to use a modal 'mask' overlay.

The grayed out transparent mask that covers the entire page, except for the element you're interacting with, eg. modal popup window.

You could do a mini version of it just within the popup and push the three non active divs behind it with CSS z-index.

One more way is to use the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

Answer (score 2):

I personally like using something like this

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Disable's click events