# jQuery deactivate click event on one div when another div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, bind, unbind

I'm currently making a website and I have 2 clickable divs "#coloursettings" and "#powersettings" both successfully unbind the menu ("#tab a") but I want each clickable div to deactivate the other, then re-activate it when clicked again. I've tried entering the corresponding ID into the same method that unbinds/binds the "#tab a" but it doesn't deactivate the other clickable div. Can anyone help make this work?

```
//Colour Settings Menu//
var clicked1 = true;
$("#coloursettings").click(function() {
    $("#colourselect").toggle();

    $(".content, .tab").toggleClass('blur');

    if (clicked1) {
        $("#tab a").unbind("click", foo);
        clicked1 = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#tab a").click(foo);
        clicked1 = true;
    }       
});

//Power Menu//
var clicked = true;
$("#powersettings").click(function() {
    $("#powermenu").toggle();

    $(".content, .tab").toggleClass('blur');

    if (clicked) {
        $("#tab a").unbind("click", foo);
        clicked = false;
    }
    else {
        $("#tab a").click(foo);
        clicked = true;
    }       
});
```

Relevant HTML

```
<div class="icon" id="coloursettings">...</div>
<div class="icon" id="powersettings">...</div>
```

[Here's a link to my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw555000/6W5Hv/)

Comment: Why don't you just toggle disabled on each button? Ah, maybe they are not `<button>`s.

Comment: they're not <button>s they're just clickable divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your needs properly or not, still tried to help you . see the below link if your needs are satisfied or not..

```
//Colour Settings Menu//
var clicked1 = false;
$("#coloursettings").click(function () {
    if (clicked) {
        return;
    }
    $("#colourselect").toggle();
    $(".content, .tab").toggleClass('blur');
    if (clicked1) {
        //$("#tab a").unbind("click", foo);
        clicked1 = false;
    } else {
        //$("#tab a").click(foo);
        clicked1 = true;
    }
});
//Power Menu//
var clicked = false;
$("#powersettings").click(function () {
    if (clicked1) {
        return;
    }
    $("#powermenu").toggle();
    $(".content, .tab").toggleClass('blur');
    if (clicked) {
        //$("#tab a").unbind("click", foo);
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        //$("#tab a").click(foo);
        clicked = true;
    }
});
//foo
function foo(e) {
    if(clicked || clicked1)
    {
        return;
    }
    hideContentDivs();
    var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
    $('.main #content').eq(tmp_div).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

[See This](http://jsfiddle.net/6W5Hv/6/)

Comment: It did work in de-activating and reactivating the clickable divs but it stopped the tabs from deactivating.

Comment: Okay.. Let me check once again

Comment: @aw555000 :: Updated answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You have several elements with `id="tab"`, don't do that. `$('#tab')` will only select one node. If you don't need the ids, just use classes : `$('.tab')` or `$('.menu .tab')`.

If I understand correctly : you are trying to "disable" `a` links with custom click handlers.
One way to do this is to use a marker class (for example : `disabled`) and have your handler check if that class is present :

```
var clicked1 = false;
$("#coloursettings").click(function(){
     ...
     clicked1 = !clicked1;
     $('.menu .tab a').toggleClass('disabled', clicked1);
});

// in your $('.menu .tab a').click() handler :
$('.menu .tab a').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ){
        return; // don't do anything if disabled
    }

    //otherwise : do stuff
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to disable and re-enabled the clickable divs "#powersettings" and "#coloursettings" when the other is clicked/unclicked. The unbind/rebind of "#tab a" already works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, you are using id's multiple times in your markup.  An id can only be used once per page.

That said, to disable a "button" in jquery, do something like this:

Add the following to the beginning of your `$("#coloursettings").click` function:

```
 $("#powersettings").addClass("disabled");
```

Then, add this to the beginning of the `$("#powersettings").click` function:

```
 if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    exit;
 }
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6W5Hv/3/

Then just do the same thing for the other button.

But the most important thing to remember...  ID's only once per page!! ;-)

Comment: I'm aware of my multiple ID issue. I changed it from "addClass" to "toggleClass" and it works as intended on the "#coloursettings" menu but doesn't work when applied to the "#powersettings" menu

Comment: if you want to create an updated fiddle, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling and enabling clicking on the divs:

[Disable div click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056229/disable-div-click-events)

Comment: They are not button elements

Comment: Sorry @Nigel. Modified the answer

Comment: @RajeevNair - It works at deactivating the other button when I assign "$('#powersettings').off" to if clicked 1 but doesn't reactivate it when I used "$('#powersettings').on".